# SELECT with condition on second table, show information from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I m try to make a select from one table based on register of a second table

i m using 4 tables

```
table Products
Product_Id     |  Product_Name    |   Product_Value   | Category_Id
1              |  Ball            |   10              | 1
2              |  Pen             |    2              | 2 
3              |  Eraser          |    1              | 1

table Categories
Category_Id    |  Category_Name
1              |  Acessories
2              |  Others

table Customers
Customer_Id    |  Customer_Name
1              |  John
2              |  Peter

table Sells
Sell_Id        |  Product_Id      |   Customer_Id   |  Sell_Date
1              |  1               |   1             |  2012-01-01
2              |  2               |   1             |  2012-01-02
```

So i want to make a select to show on customer historic what he buy

like

John Historic

```
Product Name  Category Name   Date
Ball          Accessories     2012-01-01
Pen           Others          2012-010
```

On final i am showing information form 3 different tables

I have try using INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN but with no success.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break it down: THe first thing you want is a Product Name:

```
SELECT Product_Name FROM Products
```

How do we get the category? Join it in!

```
SELECT Products.Product_Name, Categories.Category_Name 
FROM Products JOIN Categories ON Products.Category_Id = Categories.Category_Id
```

Getting close! Time to bring in the order history:

```
SELECT Products.Product_Name, Categories.Category_Name, Sells.Sells_Date 
FROM Products 
JOIN Categories ON Products.Category_Id = Categories.Category_Id
JOIN Sells ON Sells.Sells_Id = Products.Product_Id
```

Now we can bring in the name, and filter to John:

```
SELECT Products.Product_Name, Categories.Category_Name, Sells.Sells_Date 
FROM Products 
JOIN Categories ON Products.Category_Id = Categories.Category_Id
JOIN Sells ON Sells.Sells_Id = Products.Product_Id
JOIN Customers ON Sells.Customer_Id = Customers.Customer_Id
WHERE Customers.Customer_Name = 'John'
```

Just take it one step at a time in your mind. Build the query from each part as you go.

### Since you mentioned it...

`LEFT JOIN` is how you deal with missing data. It returns rows from the "left" table, and puts `NULL` in the fields of the "right" table if there is no match for the `ON` clause.

For example, if John bought a Product with no category (`Product.Category_Id` was `NULL`), using a `JOIN` would not return that record of purchase because there was no matching Category with `Category_Id` `Null`. In that case, you could `LEFT JOIN Categories` and in the result set, `Category_Name` would be `NULL` as well.

Comment: Really nice and step by step explanation. [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96b6b/6)

Comment: there as my error, i had using JOIN only and couple products dont had a category so the results was wrong, change to left join and change a bit the query works fine.. thanks.. also most of the answers are right but yours is more complete. thanks again @akatakritos

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    Customers.Customer_Name as 'Customer Name',
    Products.Product_Name as 'Product Name',
    Categories.Category_Name as 'Category Name',
    Sells.Sell_Date as 'Date Sold'
FROM Customers
    INNER JOIN Sells on Sells.Customer_Id = Customers.Customer_Id
    INNER JOIN Products ON Products.Product_Id = Sells.Sell_Id
    INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.Category_Id = Products.Category_ID;
```

If you want to pull the history up for a single person, you can use a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Customers.Customer_Id = 1
```

or...

```
WHERE Customers.Customer_Name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use JOIN on all of these tables and select whatever you want:

```
SELECT 
    p.Product_Name, c.Category_Name, s.Sell_Date
FROM
    Customers cu JOIN Sells s ON cu.id = s.Customer_Id
    JOIN Products p ON p.id = s.Product_Id     
    JOIN Categories c ON p.Category_Id = c.id
WHERE
    cu.Customer_Name = "John"
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` is correct:

```
SELECT Products.Product_Name, Categories.Category_Name, Sells.Sell_Date
FROM Sells JOIN Products ON Sells.Product_Id = Products.Product_Id JOIN Categories ON Sells.Category_Id = Categories.Category_Id
WHERE Sells.Customer_Id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product_Name, Category_Name, Sell_Date
FROM Products, Categories, Sells
WHERE Sells.Customer_Id = 1
    AND Sells.Product_Id = Products.Product_Id
    AND Products.Category_Id = Categories.Category_Id;
```